# Reason for the Windows 10 Security notification icon exclamation mark

Tags: windows-10

In the last years I've often seen (on different physical Workstations and also virtual machines with different Windows 10 SKUs and versions) that the Windows 10 security notification icon ( `SecurityHealthSystray.exe` ) shows a yellow exclamation mark for no obvious reason.

This also happens with the latest fully patched 1803 edition and also with the latest insider preview build 17733.

[image: Windows 10 Security Exclamation Icon]

Is there any method available (e.g. log file or command) to check what has triggered the display of the exclamation mark?

Note: Killing and restarting the `SecurityHealthSystray.exe` process fixes the issue most of the times.